# How to create a threadsafe insert or update with hibernate.(Dealing with optimistic locking)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, thread-safety

My problem. 
I have a simple table, token. It has only a few attributes. id, token,username,version and a expire_date. 
I have a rest service that will create or update a token. So when a user request a token, I would like to check if the user (using the username) already has an entry, if yes, then simply update the expire_date and return, if there is no entry create a new one. The problem is that if I create a test with a few concurrent users(using a jmeter script), that call the rest service, hibernate will very fast 
throw a StaleObject exception because what happens is: Thread A will select the row for the user, change the expire_date, bump the version, meanwhile thread B  will do the same but will actually manage to commit before thread A commits. Now when thread A will commit hibernate detects the version change and will throw the exception and rollback. All works as documented.

But what I would like to happen, is that Thread B will wait for Thread A to finish before doing it's thing.

What is the best way to solve this? Should I use java concurrency package and implement locks? Or is it a better option to implement a custom jpa isolation level?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JEE server, EJB container will do it for you using @Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using JPA lock to acquire lock on resources you are currently updating(row lock). Don't push your effort to implement row locking using java concurrency by your self. Ex: it will be much easier to lock row contain user "john.doe" in dbms level rather finding a way locking a specific row using concurrency in your code.

Comment: its not difficult you just have to annotate with @Transactional(Isolation=Serializable) and it will deal with these things.